# Hosting Django APIs with Celery, Redis and ELK on AWS

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, redis, celery, elk

I need some suggestions with the architecture of our application. The details are as follows:

1. The application is being written in Django and hosted on AWS.
2. We are using RDBMS as PostgreSQL and the ELK Stack (Open Source based, not the one provided by AWS) for storing Unstructured data for fast retrieval etc.

So, my queries are:

1. Currently we are using EC2 instances for hosting the application, but we would like to move to Serverless architecture and use AWS Fargate. Could someone please point towards how this can be done?
2. We would like to use Celery and Redis to be used along with Django and host the same on AWS, but not 100% sure on how this can be done.
3. How to incorporate/host the Open Source ELK on AWS? And that too along with AWS Fargate?
4. How to use/enable the API Gateway and the Elastic Load Balancer in AWS for hosting the Django APIs?

Regards,
Subhash

I'm unable to find a way to incorporate Celery and Redis with AWS Fargate.

Also, I'm not sure if Open Source ELK can be hosted on AWS.